# Power series of $1/(1+x^2)$ around arbitrary a

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I've been trying to show that $f(x)=1/(1+x^{2})$
  has a power series expansion around any point $a\in\mathbb{R}$
 .

If $a=0$
  then I can see that for $\left|x\right|<1$
  (s.t. $\left|x^{2}\right|<1$
 ) we have $1/(1+x^{2})=1/(1-(-x^{2}))=\sum(-x^{2})^{k}$.

Is there are similar strategy of simplifying to a geometric series for general $a\in\mathbb{R}$
 ? Or are there other smart ways of attacking the problem?

I would be very grateful for any answers or hints on how to proceed.

Comment: I think Taylor series of $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{1-(-x^2)}$ will do the work.

You can see the Taylor expansion of $\dfrac{1}{1-x},~|x|\lt 1$ [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TaylorSeries.html). Use the same approach as you did for the Maclaurin series.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas He wants the Taylor series around something other than $0$.

Comment: By the way, if you can get this result without going to complex numbers, you can show that the radius of convergence is $\sqrt{1+a^2}$. This is interesting because that indicates there is an "obstruction" to the somewhere a unit distance away from $0$ at a perpendicular to the real line. This gives a hint that imaginary numbers exist even when we are only looking at real functions.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, see the link I provided. It lists the Taylor series about $x=a$, not Maclaurin which is about $x=0$.

Comment: You said "for $|x|<1$ in your comment, so I assumed you were talking about the series around $0$. The Maclaurin series is a Taylor series, after all, and the transformation of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is not going to work using the taylor series for $\frac{1}{1-u}$ around $a^2$ and then replace it with what? That's not going to be useful. @PrasunBiswas

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, Ah, I see now the error I made! Thanks for correcting me though. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First use partial fraction as

> $$ \frac{1}{(1+x^2)} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{x+i} -\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{x-i}. $$

Then we find the Taylor series at the point $x=a$ as

> $$\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{x+i}= \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{(x-a)+(a+i)}= \frac{1}{2(a+i)\left(1+\frac{(x-a)}{a+i}\right)}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k(x-a)^k}{(a+i)^{k+1}}. $$

Do the other one and then try to simplify things and you will have a nice series representation.

Comment: Although this is hijacking an older question: could it be that your partial fraction decomposition is wrong? I have $$\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\frac{\mathrm i}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x+\mathrm i}-\frac{1}{x-\mathrm i}\right).$$

Answer (score 2):

Without going into the complex numbers...

Letting $u=x-a$, we have:

$$\frac{1}{1+x^2} = \frac1{1+a^2+2au+u^2}= \frac 1{a^2+1}\frac{1}{1+\frac{2au+u^2}{a^2+1}}$$

Then expand $\frac{1}{1+v}=\sum (-v)^k$ with $v=\frac{2au+u^2}{a^2+1}$.

That gives you a rather messy formula. The coefficient of $(x-a)^n$ is going to be gotten by finding the coefficient of $u^n$ in  $$\left(-\frac{2au+u^2}{1+a^2}\right)^i$$ for $\lceil n/2\rceil \leq i \leq n$ combine them. That's the $n-i$ coefficient of

$$\left(-\frac{2a+u}{1+a^2}\right)^i$$

Which is $$\binom{i}{n-i}(2a)^{2i-n}\left(\frac{-1}{a^2+1}\right)^i$$

So the $n$th coefficient is (because we had the additional $\frac{1}{a^2+1}$ outside the sum:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i\frac{\binom{i}{n-i}(2a)^{2i-n}}{(a^2+1)^{i+1}} =\frac{1}{(1+a^2)^{n+1}}\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i\binom{i}{n-i}(2a)^{2i-n}(1+a^2)^{n-i}$$

Note that we can go from $0$ to $n$ because when $i<\lceil n/2\rceil$, $n-i>i$ and the coefficient evaluates to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Since science gave a nice formal and general answer, for sure, the following is not a full answer to the question.

Applying the definitions (and being patient), you could  show that Taylor expansion around $x=a$ write as $$\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nP_n(a)}{(1+a^2)^{n+1}}(x-a)^n$$ with $$P_0(a)=1$$ $$P_1(a)=2a$$  $$P_2(a)=3a^2-1$$ $$P_3(a)=4a^3-4a$$ $$P_4(a)=5a^4-10a^2+1$$ $$P_5(a)=6 a^5-20 a^3+6 a$$ $$P_6(a)=7 a^6-35 a^4+21 a^2-1$$ in which some patterns seem to appear (different for odd and even values of $n$).

Comment: My answer gives the same polynomials, but it still isn't in the "obvious" closed form that you point out is right there in the first $6$ examples.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews. I totally agree with you, be sure and I really like you answer. Thanks & cheers :-)

Comment: Certainly, the complex number view makes it clear - you are looking for the imaginary part of $(a-i)^{k+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to this problem I came up with
$$
\begin{align*}
 \frac{1}{1+z^2}
 &= \frac{1}{(z-\mathrm i)(z+\mathrm i)} \\
 &= \frac{1}{2\mathrm i(z-\mathrm i)} - \frac{1}{2\mathrm i(z+\mathrm i)} \\
 &= \frac{1}{2\mathrm i}\left( \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(z-x)^n}{(z-\mathrm i)^{n+1}} - \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(z-x)^n}{(z+\mathrm i)^{n+1}} \right)\\
 &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2\mathrm i} \left( \frac{1}{(z-\mathrm i)^{n+1}} - \frac{1}{(z+\mathrm i)^{n+1}} \right)(x-z)^n.
\end{align*}
$$
This series has the radius of convergence $|x-\mathrm i|=\sqrt{1+x^2}$.